# Is there any POST API of linkedin to make changes to user profile

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have a list of projects for various users and the description of those projects stored in a database. I want to POST this data on a users profile upon his consent so that he doesn't have to do it and it automatically happens on runtime without any activity from the user.

Comment: what about going through linked in api?

Comment: I tried that. But I couldn't find an API which actually lets me do that! Because as a single developer, I don't have permissions to do it. That is the conclusion I came to with what I have researched as of now. Which is why I posted here to find if there is a way out!

Comment: _as a single developer, I don't have permissions to do it..._ So there you have your ansswer

Comment: See, isn't that the whole point of this platform. If I think it is not possible, I am trying to figure out if someone else thinks this is possible and if yes, what is the way to do it